# Filling Word Document with text ( Modifying it with styles and all) Create Contract document with c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

[this is the picture of sample i have to create .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuEOQ.png) I want to Create a word document and fill it with text, this document should look like a contract word file. It should have paragraphs with its styles and all sort of things(page for example headers) and in the last page it should have 
Document seal . Can anyone provide with materials or code ?

```
    object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
doc.Paragraphs.Add();
Word.Range objRange = doc.Content;
objRange.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);

objRange.Text = "Bold text aligned center" + Environment.NewLine;
objRange.Bold = 1;
objRange.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
objRange.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);

objRange.Text = "Regular text aligned left" + Environment.NewLine;
objRange.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
objRange.Bold = 0;
objRange.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);

objRange.Text = "Regular text aligned center\nwith something on the next line" + Environment.NewLine;
objRange.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
objRange.Bold = 0;
objRange.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);

objRange.Text = "Regular text aligned left, with some ";
objRange.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
objRange.Text = "Bold text here";
objRange.Bold = 1;
objRange.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
objRange.Text = "\nand some regular text on next line" + Environment.NewLine;
objRange.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
objRange.Bold = 0;
```

found this code but i cant figure things out.

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; Cant find this using thing as well. can you help me with this reference ?

Comment: to add the reference follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944379/where-can-i-find-microsoft-office-interop-word-dll-2010)

Comment: i added nugets and it fixed i can create a word document now with some texts inside. now i need to add number the  pages.

Comment: "now i need to add number the pages" Please post that as a new question.

Comment: The best approach would be to create the base text and format  of the contract as a word template. If you must use interop rather than VBA then use interop to create a document based on the template, modify the document as required (e.g. date, supplier, requirements fields, addition/deletion of paragraphs) and then save (as word or pdf).  Creating a document from scratch using interop doesn't seem sensible.